# Ionic 3: Position modal window to bottom right of the screen

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, modal-dialog, ionic3, css-position

I've tried everything, don't get it.

Just want to fix the modal popup window to the bottom right corner of the screen, that's it.

This is how I'm showing my modal:

```
let modal = this._ModalController.create(MyPage, { group: group }, {cssClass: 'custom-modal' });
modal.present();
```

And I was trying css, but with no luck:

```
.custom-modal {
  .modal-wrapper {
    position: absolute !important;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it with:

```
@media only screen and (min-height: 600px) and (min-width: 768px)
{
  .custom-modal {
    .modal-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      width: 766px !important;
      height: 500px !important;
      top: calc(100% - (500px));
      left: calc(100% - (766px)) !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done some trick to deal with modal size n all.

First of all put this css into app.scss

```
modal-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  @media not all and (min-height: 600px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    ion-modal ion-backdrop {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (min-height: 0px) and (min-width: 0px) {
    .modal-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  }
```

then in your modal page scss you can  play with your modal design

this is how i did.

testpage.html

```
<ion-content class="main-view" scrollY="true">
  <div class="overlay"></div>

  <div class="modal_content">

    <ion-header>

      <ion-navbar>

        <ion-title>Test</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end>
          <button ion-button (click)="closeModal()">Close</button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-navbar>

    </ion-header>

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

and here is magic works with testPage.scss

```
test-modal {

        .main-view{
          background: transparent;
        }
        .overlay {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          z-index: 1;
          opacity: .5;
          background-color: #333;
        }
        .modal_content {
          position: absolute;
          top: calc(50% - (65%/2));
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          width: 90%;
          // height: 80%;
          padding: 10px;
          z-index: 100;
          margin: 0 auto;
          padding: 10px;
          color: #333;
          background: #e8e8e8;
          background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
          background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
          background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
          border-radius: 5px;
          box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(51, 51, 51, .35);
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  More than I needed, but useful, so will leave for others here.

Answer (score 0):

try defining the properties in the global `app.scss` file, not in the scss-file of the page you are trying to show in the modal.

See this:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-make-certain-modals-fullscreen/102956